# Edit a data in a xml file using XMLConfiguration()

Tags: java, xml

i little confused how to edit an xml content,
e.g.  I have an xml file

```
<configuration>
<steps>
<step>
    <step1>abc</step1>
    <step2>def</step2>
</step>

<step>
    <step1>pqr</step1>
    <step2>xyz</step2>
</step>
</steps>
</configuration>
```

how can I edit the "xyz" to "stu"

I tried to use XMLConfiguration of commons-configuration-1.6.jar

```
setProp(String name, String tochange){ // here I pass name as  "pqr" , toChange as "stu"
      XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("config.xml");
      //TODO: config.setProperty("steps.step.step2",tochange); Here I am not sure what to do..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
steps.step(1).step2
```

in order to identify the second step node. See [this doc](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide-1.2/howto_xml.html) for more info. Note that it indexes from 0, not 1 (unlike, say, XPath).

Comment: Hey Brian! Congrats for 100K :)

Comment: it workes .. instead it starts its indexing from 0 .. so we can use steps.setp(1).step2

Comment: @ranjan - I've amended appropriately. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("config.xml");
config.addProperty("steps.step(2).step2",tochange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to edit "xyz" to "stu" and display xml

public class DataChange {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
    XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("change.xml");
    config.setProperty("steps.step(1).step2", "stu");       
    StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
    config.save(s);
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}
```

}